# Trigger Jenkin job from team city and get the report posted to team city

Tags: jenkins, teamcity

I need to trigger Jenkins job from team city and post the reports from Jenkins back to team city. To trigger build in Jenkins I am using curl command which is working fine.

How to post the report back to team city?

Comment: which report are you talking about?

Comment: The jenkins job is set up to run some automation tests. I am generating Cucumber reports.

Comment: I am looking for a way to store the reports to the artifacts in Team City